# Linq list inside List query

Tags: .net, linq

```
Class A
{
   string name;
   IList<A> minorList = new List<A>();
}

IList<A> majorList = new List<A>();
```

I Want to get the instance of A from `majorList` depending upon the name value, but it is not necessary to have it in the `majorList`. `minorList` can also contain the name. How can I get it using Linq. If it is there in only `majorList` I can get it by using

```
A a = majorList.First(s => s.Name == "Name");
```

How about if it is not in the majorList but in some of the List of instance of majorList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
bool ContainsName(A a, string name)
{
    return a.name == name || a.minorList.Any(x => ContainsName(x, name));
}
```

Then:

```
A a = majorList.First(x => ContainsName(x, name));
```

Of course you end up with a problem if there are any cycles in your lists...

Comment: Hi Jon, is this correct one?? `A a = majorList.First(x => {return a.name == name || minorList.Any(x => ContainsName(x, name));});`

Comment: @NiranjanKala: No - you've got to have the method otherwise you can't call it recursively... and if you've got the method, you might as well call it from the lambda expression.

Comment: thanks Jon, +1 for resolving my confusion and this nice answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Jon for the great answer.